# Extract day from a pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

## Goal

I would like to **extract the day** (i.e."2022-10-10") **from a pandas Timestamp** - in the local timezone if possible.

## Example

```
from pandas import Timestamp
t = Timestamp('2022-10-10 06:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T')
```

## What I have tried

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Issue:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```py
from pandas import Timestamp
t = Timestamp('2022-10-10 06:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T')
# get date object from timestamp
date = t.date()
# format date to string
date_str = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `t.to_pydatetime()`. It returns `datetime` object.

```py
t = Timestamp('2022-10-10 06:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T')

t.to_pydatetime()
>> datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 10, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

t.to_pydatetime().year
>> 2022

t.to_pydatetime().month
>> 10

t.to_pydatetime().day
>> 10
```